# pywinauto Afx:RibbonBar no control types

Tags: pywinauto

The application I am trying to automate has a ribbonbar and when I execute print_control_identifiers on the ribbon bar in question, I dont see any controls exposed. Is there a way to automate controls inside the ribbon bar?

Any help is much appreciated

```
Toolbar - ''    (L0, T0, R1920, B143)
['Toolbar', '']
child_window(auto_id="59398", control_type="ToolBar")
```

Inspect.exe

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
Name:   ""
ControlType:    UIA_ToolBarControlTypeId (0xC365)
LocalizedControlType:   "tool bar"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:0 t:0 r:1920 b:143}
ClassName:  "Afx:RibbonBar:400000:8:10003:10"
HelpText:   "ControlPane"
```

**Mouse Move on Ribbon**

```
How found:  Mouse move (593,98)
hwnd=0x00000000001703B8 32bit class="Afx:RibbonBar:400000:8:10003:10" style=0x54002800 ex=0x0
 Name:  ""
 ControlType:   UIA_ToolBarControlTypeId (0xC365)
 LocalizedControlType:  "tool bar"
 AutomationId:  "59398"
 FrameworkId:   "Win32"
 ClassName: "Afx:RibbonBar:400000:8:10003:10"
 NativeWindowHandle:    0x1703B8
 ProviderDescription:   "[pid:5348,hwnd:0x1703B8 Main:Nested [pid:3852,hwnd:0x1703B8 Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
```

**Mouse Move on a control**

```
How found:  Mouse move (31,89)
            hwnd=0x00000000001703B8 32bit class="Afx:RibbonBar:400000:8:10003:10" style=0x54002800 ex=0x0
Name:   "Create"
ControlType:    UIA_ButtonControlTypeId (0xC350)
LocalizedControlType:   "button"
AccessKey:  "Alt, H, C"
ProcessId:  3852
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:3852,hwnd:0x0 Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    "Press"
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  "Create a new batch"
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: "Alt, H, C"
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Create"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: push button (0x2B)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    focusable (0x100000)
```

Comment: Is this app available for download?

Comment: I'm sorry, it can't be downloaded; it is a paid work application. Let me know if you need any information about the application and I can provide that and thank you for looking into the issue

Comment: OK, is it possible to hover mouse over toolbar button and see it in Inspect.exe?

Comment: Hi Vasily, I have updated the question with Inspect information

Comment: Thanks! It's technically possible to obtain buttons info, but it's not a high priority task for now. See [issue #413](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/413). Your case is pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks. I do hope this gets incorporated into pywinauto soon

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for `backend="uia"` is implemented in `pywinauto==0.6.6`. So toolbar method `.button('Button name')` should return wrapper for correct UI element. There might be only one problem left: drop-down menu items in a menu bar can't be automated yet. First level buttons / menu items are OK to automate now.